# ffmpeg generate thumbnails differents scales

Tags: split, ffmpeg, thumbnails, scale

Hi this is possible using one command generate differente thumbnails with different scale images?

```
ffmpeg -i "rod.mp4" -vf "thumbnail,scale=560:-1,pad=max(iw\,ih):420:(ow-iw)/2:(oh-ih)/2" -frames:v 1 best560x420.png -vf "thumbnail,scale=320:-1,pad=max(iw\,ih):240:(ow-iw)/2:(oh-ih)/2" -frames:v 1 best320x240.png -vf "thumbnail,scale=320:-1,pad=max(iw\,ih):240:(ow-iw)/2:(oh-ih)/2" -frames:v 1  best320x240.png
```

This command is very inefficient.

Using

> -vf split??

Thank's

Answer (score 2):

This command generate thumbnails in different scales:

```
ffmpeg -ss 00:05:00 -t 1 -i "file.mp4"  -filter_complex 'split=4[a][b][c][d];[a]scale=-1:360[o360p];[b]scale=-1:240[o240p];[c]scale=-1:480[o480p];[d]scale=-1:720[o720p]' -map '[o360p]' -frames:v 1 out-360p.png -map '[o240p]' -frames:v 1 out-240p.png -map '[o480p]' -frames:v 1 out-480p.png -map '[o720p]' -frames:v 1 out-720p.png
```

Comment: -ss represent the seek position where the screenshot will take place, I thinks it will generate an error in case the video is less than 5min with this commande, -ss 1 is good for tests